# How to add several @ManyToMany relations in one JPA transaction?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have 2 entities with `@ManyToMany` relation like that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "payments")
@TypeDef(name = "hstore", typeClass = PostgreSQLHStoreType.class)
public class PaymentEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "payment_gen",
            strategy = "com.openpayment.impl.entity.ManualSequenceIdentifier",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "payments_id_seq")
            }
    )
    @GeneratedValue(generator="payment_gen")
    private Long id;

}
```

(of course they are other columns, but omitted for brevity)

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "registries")
public class RegistryEntity {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="registries_gen", sequenceName="registries_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="registries_gen")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "registry_payments",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "registry_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "payment_id"))
    private Collection<PaymentEntity> payments;

}
```

(other columns are also omitted)

So, the `RegistryEntity` has a join table to refer the `PaymentEntity`.

Then, in one transaction I

1. Create 2 different `RegistryEntity` JPA objects
2. Assign a list of the same `PaymentEntity`'s (let it be a list of size=2)
3. consequently persist both `RegistryEntity`

   ```
    @Transactional
    public void doTask() {
    execute();
    }

    public void execute() {
    List<PaymentEntity> payments1 = paymentDao.getRegistryPaymentsConditionFisrt();
    savePayments(payments1);
    List<PaymentEntity> payments2 = paymentDao.getRegistryPaymentsConditionSecond();
    // first and second condition return the same payments at the first run
    savePayments(payments2);
    }

    public void savePayments(List<PaymentEntity> payments) {
    RegistryEntity registryEntity = new RegistryEntity();
    if (payments.size() > 0) {
        registryEntity.setPayments(payments);
    }       
    registryDao.persist(registryEntity);
    }
   ```

I expect: the join table would have 4 extra values, each `RegistryEntity` assigned to each `PaymentEntity`.

Actual result: only unique values of `PaymentEntity` ids are inserted at the same time. I.e. in Join table there are only entries for all `PaymentEntity` and the only `RegistryEntity`. Like I have never tried to add the same payments to the second registry.

I need to rerun the transaction, excluding the addition of already added elements and thus the insert occurs. Excluding occurs because of DB trigger, that changes the column, that doesn't allow to pick up that at the fisrtCondition, but allows only to pick up at the second condition.

So it looks, lie for JPA perspective, `PaymentEntity` in both list are still the same. It ignores that it was added to the first `RegistryEntity`, since it was added to the first one. My expectation is that it shouldn't be treated on `PaymentEntity` side, but on `RegistryEntity` side, which should distinguish the and allow to be the same payment added to the different registry at once.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: When you commit the transaction, do you get inserts for two separate RegistryEntity instances? You mentioned a DB trigger is involved in excluding - can you elaborate on what your trigger is doing exactly or why it would be involved in changing columns and excluding conditions? JPA would not ignore the list being added to the second registryEntity, though your provider might have issues if the List is the same instance shared into two entities.

Comment: @Chris trigger just updates the table with boolean flags like 'sentTo1' and 'sentTo2' that are updated on some subsequent change after the doTask() exectution. So here the trigger is just a way how to return the first payments list empty because of added change

Comment: @Chris I do get inserts, but they appear in the registries table and the first entity is mentioned by the join table and its join to the payments, while the second registry is inserted, but stays orphan, there are no entries in the join table that refer it

Comment: Still don't know why a trigger is involved. What is in that second list exactly? Maybe verify with a simple test case that uses your model on a DB that doesn't have triggers that your model and the code work, as it is certainly something you aren't showing that is causing the issue.

Comment: @Chris may be. But now I have found the workaround. I have created the separate methods and transactions for something that takes payments from the DAO and calls savePayments(). 2 separate transactions removed the problem